# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable discord.py + PIL

Tags: discord.py, python-imaging-library

I need an event that, when sending a message, sends a picture to the chat, on which the text with the guild.member_count variable is written using the PIL library, but it gives an error, what am I doing wrong?

```
async def on_message(ctx):
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild.id)
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel.id)
    new_img = Image.open('image.png')
    font = ImageFont.truetype("MabryPro-Regular.ttf", 100)
    pencil = ImageDraw.Draw(new_img)
    pencil2 = ImageDraw.Draw(new_img)
    pencil.text((28, 650), guild.member_count, font=font, fill='black', size=1000)
    with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
        new_img.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
        image_binary.seek(0)
        await channel.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='image.png'))
```

Error:

````
2022-12-30 09:48:45 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RainWon\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RainWon\PycharmProjects\bot\bot.py", line 108, in on_message
    pencil.text((28, 650), guild.member_count, font=font, fill='black', size=1000)
  File "C:\Users\RainWon\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 422, in text
    if self._multiline_check(text):
  File "C:\Users\RainWon\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 384, in _multiline_check
    return split_character in text
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable```
````

Answer (score 0):

The text should be a string, you're passing an int (`guild.member_count`). Just put `str()` around it.